# Jquery / Jquery Tools Getting Smaller Effect

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-tools

I want to develop a screen with JQuery Tools(or just with JQuery) and HTML5. There will be a main panel at screen and it will have rounded square buttons on it. When user clicks a button this panel will get smaller and will be place at left side, something will appear at right side.

I mean:

[image: clicking]

Squares inside of big squares symbolizes buttons. When a user click a button at 1, panel will get smaller and go to left as like 2.

I may use that: [JQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/index.html)

Comment: Why should we do it using jQuery Tools? We might want to use CSS3 and CSS3 transformation instead. Also, what have you tried already?

Comment: I should implement it with JQuery Tools cos it will be a part of a big application and all infrastructure will be with Jquery Tools. However if there any easy way to implement it, you are welcome.

Comment: Not sure I've got the time to do my day job and your job. What have you tried already?

Comment: This is a given job for me and JQuery Tools will be used also JQuery is welcome. I examined all the demos of the JQuery Tools however I need a start point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I [**found some time**](http://jsfiddle.net/t4XmU/) after all. Seems to work for me in Chrome 15, so will probably work in other webkit-based browsers as well. It's only a starting point so the cross-browser code needs some attention.

**Edit:** [**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t4XmU/1/) which uses the [shrinkTo jQuery plugin](http://www.twoixter.com/experiments/jquery-growshrink)

#### HTML

```
<a href="#" id="shrinkify">Shrinkify me</a>
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="big">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#big {
    width:240px;
    height:240px;
    border:4px solid black;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:relative;
    left:200px;
}

#big a {
    display:inline-block;
    border:2px solid black;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    width:55px;
    height:55px;
}

#small {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('#shrinkify').click(function() {
    $('div#big').shrinkTo($('#small'), {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        opacity: false
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help and seems that you spend time for it however I need it to get smaller with an effect

Comment: Specifying what sort of effect you want in your question would result in me updating my answer :-)

Comment: I've added a second demo that uses a jQuery plugin for the scaling. I am not sure if it's exactly what you are after but it was fun to build :-)

Answer (score 1):

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J3cUz/3/)

The following will work for Chrome, Safari, FF 4+ and Opera 10+.  The magic is in CSS3 `transform` and `transition`.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="r">Reset</a>
<div id="z"><!-- this is the button container --></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#z a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#z').addClass('dock');
});
$('#r').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#z').removeClass('dock');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#z {
    position: absolute; left: 150px; top: 150px;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-tranform: scale(1.1);
    transition: 0.6s ease-in;
    -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; // prevent webkit bug
}

#z.dock {
    left: -70px; top: -10px;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    -o-transform: scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    transition: 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; // prevent webkit bug
}
```

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J3cUz/3/)

Comment: Very nice, thanks for your answer but how we can do that with JQuery effects? I don't want it get small suddenly, can we add an event for it?

Comment: I think it has an animation effect at Opera.