# How to animate all the elements of a group with JQuery - menu example?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, jquery-tools

I have an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kamaci/uVQZc/3/

When I animate bigger blue div, I want to be resized that buttons too. Actually I can put more elements inside of that div and I can put elements inside of elements. So I need a generic structure that when the bigger container get resized, inside of its elements resized too.

Resize operation could be done via percentage but I couldn't find a solution for that: [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077085/how-can-i-both-move-a-div-and-resize-it-with-animation-effect-at-jquery/7079343#comment-8489923)

All in all what I want to do is I want to make a menu and when a user clicks a button on that menu that menu will go to left side(with an animation). related question:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075230/jquery-jquery-tools-getting-smaller-effect)

I want a menu that has buttons as like that [simple](http://demo.ponjoh.com/Simpla-Admin/index.html#), rounded squares (I think this can be done with CSS3) actually as an example if I can use one that that buttons it would be perfect.

I want to use JQuery and Jquery Tools and HTML5.(I don't have deep knowledge about CSS)

Thanks.

Comment: Why you don't know HTML, CSS? How you expect to resize buttons? Why you use animation with '-=' without a .stop(). Have you Googled for 'CSS3 generator'? The fiddle you provided is the best so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could basically copy the one from [Jquery / Jquery Tools Getting Smaller Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075230/jquery-jquery-tools-getting-smaller-effect), but that one will only work in CSS3 compatible browsers. A more robust solution would look like this:

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6WUNP/1/)

CSS:

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #abc;
  left: 110px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}
button {
  width: 32%;
  height: 48%;
  margin: 1% 0 0 1%;

  background: #00f;

  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    top,
    #f0f0f0 0%,
    #e3e3e3);
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear, left top, left bottom, 
    from(#f0f0f0),
    to(#e3e3e3));
}
```

And remove all whitespace between the `<button>`s, since you'll get spaces between them otherwise (stupid, but true):

```
<div id="fd" class="block">
<button type="button">1!</button><button type="button">2!</button><button type="button">3!</button><button type="button">4!</button><button type="button">5!</button><button type="button">6!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Great work but can you explain your code how you could achieve this?

Comment: How I would achieve what exactly?